# Proof Map is (Inf) Norm ||A||$_∞$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation, matrix-norms

*so I have learned to proof the 1-Norm,2-Norm and p-Norm.*

*I know that max is a function, which returns the maximum in a list/array.*

**So in this example I have**:
[$\|A\|_\infty$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKzH3.png)

$$
\|A\|_\infty := \max_{1\le i\le n}\Biggl(\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|\Biggr)
$$

I know the axioms and I can use them on the previously mentioned norms except the Inf-Norm :/

***How do I handle max?***

**My attempt**:
Let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with
$\|A\|_\infty= \max(|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)$

Well thats it, I usually show that it has to be equal or greater then $0$, since the squareroot only allows in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ non complex solutions,

hence $\|A\|_\infty = 0$ implies

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but in my example there is no $\sqrt{(a_{ij})^2}$

Also, would I simply take the maximum of i? like the biggest i? Since in the norm my matrix cant be infinite itself, it would make sense to me, but I am most of the time wrong anyways :1

I also found [Infinity matrix norm example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193260/infinity-matrix-norm-example?rq=1)

But this seems like analysis + linear algebra, since supremum is a analysis function, hence I am even more confused.

Maybe max returns the biggest (total) number in my matrix A?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you very much, I will learn the notation and edit it to optimise my question.

Comment: No. The definition should be $\|A\|_\infty=\max\limits_{\color{red}{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}}\sum_{j=1}^n|a_{ij}|$. For your $2\times2$ matrix $A$, this means $\|A\|_\infty=\max\big(|a|+|b|,\,|c|+|d|\big)$.

Comment: @user1551 omg thank you very very much! 

I very much appreciate the edeting aswell, this makes it easier for everyone to read and understand the question and algebraic expressions.

Now I see the logic behind it, it sums up the absolut values for each row and not for each element itself, and since it's the absolut value, there is no need for going for the square and quadration. Well this explains alot. Huge thanks to you. I had so much problems and difficulties to even understand what is happening :D

Comment: @user1551 Shall I post a solution to it aswell? Of course I will credit you.

Comment: By the official policy, you are welcomed to answer your own question on this site.

Comment: @user1551 very nice, well I am currently studying the max function such that my answer will fit qualitativly into this forum, always giving back to the community - oh yeaa